# Checking Status of checkbox with a variable. checkbox(i).checked ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, loops, checkbox

I have 30 checkboxes in my web form, and i want to store the status of checkboxes in a array of bool. now since asp.net doesn't accept using the "checked" status of a checkbox with a variable like "i" ,problem is i don't know how to perform the code!

i want something like this:

```
bool[] array = new bool[30];
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
   {
      array[i] = CheckBox(i).Checked ;
   }
```

when you run the above code you'll get this error:

```
Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0118: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Source Error:

Line 109:        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
Line 110:        {
Line 111:            array[i] = CheckBox(i).Checked;
Line 112:        }
Line 113:
```

I exactly want to know how can i use IDs of checkboxes with a variable, like:

```
i = 15;
CheckBox(i).Checked
```

instead of:

```
CheckBox15.Checked
```

ASP.net 4 and c#
Thank you Guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
bool[] array = new bool[30];
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
   array[i] = ((CheckBox)Page.FindControl("CheckBox" + i.ToString)).Checked;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I just created a new project just to test if the codes are working, and it worked. really. :|

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox5" runat="server" />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox6" runat="server" />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox7" runat="server" />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox8" runat="server" />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox9" runat="server" />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox10" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

code-behind:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool[] array = new bool[10];
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            array[i] = ((CheckBox)Page.FindControl("CheckBox" + i.ToString())).Checked;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It came With Error: "Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Source Error:                              Line 111:  array[i] = ((CheckBox)Page.FindControl("CheckBox" + i.ToString())).Checked;"
But thanks @vhinn terrible

Comment: Do you have a Checkbox whose ID is "CheckBox0"? if none, of course it will return NULL as it didnt see a control like that. change your for loop to start with 1 and not 0!

Comment: It's not because of that. I did what you told ans the result was the same, I also did: bool con = ((CheckBox)Page.FindControl("CheckBox10")).Checked; and it was the same. you'll wonder if i say i also tried this: string str = ((CheckBox)Page.FindControl("CheckBox10")).ID.ToString();
and result was just the same. i think it can't fine the specific control with this method at all!

Comment: Well thank you Vhinn, It worked. But with a tiny change.bool[] array = new bool[11]; That's all. thank you again.